# Getting Moz Rank for new registered website

Tags: ranking

I registered new domain and it has only one page (website is under construction page). Is it possible to increase my website moz rank only with creating backlinks? I want to increase website ranking before uploading any content.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's no gentle way of saying this.  What would someone backlink to?  It takes content and time to build trust.  I don't think any quality websites will want to link to a site that has no content and simply shows under construction.  And Google definitely doesn't want to give an "Under Construction" website any rank.

Comment: Why are you interested in Moz rank anyway?   It is a proxy metric that has no meaning on its own.  It is meant to be similar to Google Pagerank but without a website that is also meaningless because Google doesn't index under construction pages.

Answer (score 1):

Most search engines these days, Google especially will not list under construction pages. In order to achieve any form of ranking regardless of the index being ranked in your site needs to have content. Now while it is true there are quite a few single page websites out there all of these pages have something which based on your question your's appears to lack and that is useful content that would be found useful to an end user. In order to rank to any level you need to have content, unique helpful, and topic specific content generally works the best. Once your site has finished being constructed and goes live as long as it has good quality content, that isn't simply copied from other sites, and that people are interested in, then the ranking will organically grow. It is also worth mentioning that backlinks which are assessed as not being legitimate (such as backlinking from every site you can add a link to and having the links direct to an under construction page) will just result in the backlinks in question being ignored anyway.

In addition Moz ranking is not really something you need to be concerned about as it is more a predictive rating than an actual rating. It is mainly used to predict how well a domain will rank on search engine result pages, however as it is a predictive rating and not a historic rating it is not considered as important and achieving a high Moz ranking will basically do nothing for your actual search engine rankings which is how people will find your site.